# How to make C find all different symbol (+,-,*,/) combinations to have a certain output

Tags: c, combinations, equation

I have the following equation :
`8 ? 7 ? 6 ? 5 ? 4 ? 3 ? 2 ? 1 = 36` and I need to make a C program that finds which operators ( from `+, -, *, /`) go instead of `?` in order to make the equation true.

My initial thought is that I have `4*7=28` different combinations. So I started making arrays adding first all `+` then reduce the number of `+` by 1 and add another symbol and see if the equation is true. But I'm confused about the direction I took.

Also I haven't found anything similar in my many google searches, so this is my last resort.

Thanks!

Comment: recursion will solve it easily

Comment: Could you elaborate ? @AbhishekKeshri

Comment: show me what have you tried. i won't write the code from scratch.

Comment: No, you have 4 raised to the 7th power combinations. Your first job is to build an *expression parser*. Note that the grouping of the terms will change due to operator precedence. Is `/` implemented as integer division?

Comment: The number of dispositions is 4 at the power of 7, i.e. 16384. Anyway, not much.

Comment: Do * and / have higher priority than + and - ?

Comment: @Bathsheba yes the '/' is the symbol for division

Comment: Indeed, but is this *integer* division? I.e. what is 5 / 2 say? (Makes the problem a lot harder if that's 2.5 rather than 2).

Comment: @Arash It isn't specified, but it's tha same as maths , * and / have higher priority

Comment: division will be int or float?

Comment: @Bathsheba if it was exclusively integer i think it would be %, so i guess it's not integer division.

Comment: @DumDum, then it becomes difficult to solve it in a cheap way.

Comment: What you are looking for is called _permutations_ in computer science and roughly means one combination out of all possible combinations.

Comment: _if it was exclusively integer i think it would be %_: Assuming C syntax: `/` applied to two `int` expressions is an _integer_ division. Only, if at least one operand is floating point it becomes a floating point division. (Type promotion is the term to search for regarding this.) `%` is the operator symbol for [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (i.e. integer division remainder) (and may be used with integer expressions exclusively).

Comment: @Scheff You are right , my bad.

Comment: Just an idea: `+` `-` `*` `/` are four operators - can be mapped to numbers 0 ... 3 -> can be stored as 2 bits. 7 * 2 bits = 14 bits. Counting a 14 bit number from 0 to 2^14 - 1 (e.g. an `unsigned int` where only the least 14 bits are considered) should yield all possible combinations of operators. (Separation of operators should be quite easy using bit-operations `&` and `>>`.) Considering precedences is a different story.

Comment: @Scheff Thank you for your input , but i'm afraid i don't undestand what am i supposed to do :(

Comment: Working with `double` to resemble operations on Real numbers is probably not a good idea. (I'm afraid of precision issues which make the final comparison ugly.) But using fractions could be an option. For this, something like `struct Fract { int num, denom; }` would be necessary as well as the resp. functions to add, sub, mul, and div. Sounds not sooo difficult...

Comment: @Scheff wow, amazing code . Thanks for your help , much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a nice puzzle...

Here is my solution (which became smaller as I myself expected).

`findOps.c`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* too lazy to type this everytimes out... */    
typedef unsigned int uint;

/* enumeration of all supported operators */
enum {
  Add, Sub, Mul, Div
};
/* It is also used as encoding for compact storage with 2 bits. */

/* extracts operator i from ops. */
uint getOp(uint ops, uint i) { return (ops >> 2 * i) & 3; }

/* solves the equation with nValue values and (nValue - 1) ops
 * and returns the result.
 * This considers operator precedences appropriately.
 */
int solve(uint nValues, int values[], uint ops)
{
  int sum = 0; /* accu for add, subtract */
  int prod = values[0]; /* accu for multiply, divide */
  for (int i = 1; i < nValues; ++i) {
    int arg2 = values[i];
    switch (getOp(ops, i - 1)) {
      case Add:
        sum += prod;
        prod = arg2;
        break;
      case Sub:
        sum += prod;
        prod = -arg2;
        break;
      case Mul:
        prod *= arg2;
        break;
      case Div:
        prod /= arg2;
        break;
    }
  }
  sum += prod;
  return sum;
}

/* pretty prints the equation out of internal representation. */
void print(uint nValues, int values[], uint ops, int result)
{
  char chrOp[4] = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
  printf("%d", values[0]);
  for (uint i = 1; i < nValues; ++i) {
    printf(" %c %d", chrOp[getOp(ops, i - 1)], values[i]);
  }
  printf(" == %d\n", result);
}

/* main function */
int main()
{
  /* assume some kind of input which provides the arguments and intended result */
  int values[] = { 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
  enum { nValues = sizeof values / sizeof *values };
  int result = 36;
  /* check all combinations of operators */
  uint opsEnd = 1 << 2 * (nValues - 1);
  assert(8 * sizeof opsEnd >= 2 * (nValues - 1)); /* paranoid check whether opsEnd has enough bits */
  uint ops = 0;
  do {
    if (solve(nValues, values, ops) == result) {
      print(nValues, values, ops, result);
    }
  } while (++ops != opsEnd);
  /* done */
  return 0;
}
```

Test in [cygwin](http://cygwin.org) on Windows 7:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -o findOps findOps.c

$ ./findOps 
8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 == 36
8 * 7 - 6 * 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 == 36
8 * 7 - 6 - 5 * 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 == 36
8 + 7 * 6 - 5 * 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 == 36
8 * 7 - 6 - 5 - 4 * 3 + 2 + 1 == 36
8 + 7 * 6 - 5 - 4 * 3 + 2 + 1 == 36
8 + 7 + 6 * 5 - 4 * 3 + 2 + 1 == 36
8 * 7 / 6 * 5 - 4 * 3 + 2 + 1 == 36
8 * 7 / 6 * 5 / 4 * 3 + 2 + 1 == 36
8 / 7 * 6 * 5 + 4 + 3 - 2 + 1 == 36
8 + 7 * 6 / 5 * 4 - 3 - 2 + 1 == 36
8 + 7 - 6 + 5 * 4 + 3 * 2 + 1 == 36
8 + 7 / 6 + 5 * 4 + 3 * 2 + 1 == 36
8 * 7 / 6 + 5 * 4 + 3 * 2 + 1 == 36
8 * 7 - 6 - 5 - 4 - 3 * 2 + 1 == 36
8 + 7 * 6 - 5 - 4 - 3 * 2 + 1 == 36
8 + 7 + 6 * 5 - 4 - 3 * 2 + 1 == 36
8 * 7 / 6 * 5 - 4 - 3 * 2 + 1 == 36
8 + 7 + 6 + 5 * 4 - 3 * 2 + 1 == 36
8 / 7 * 6 + 5 + 4 * 3 * 2 + 1 == 36
8 / 7 * 6 * 5 + 4 + 3 / 2 + 1 == 36
8 + 7 + 6 * 5 * 4 / 3 / 2 + 1 == 36
8 * 7 - 6 * 5 / 4 * 3 + 2 - 1 == 36
8 * 7 + 6 - 5 * 4 - 3 - 2 - 1 == 36
8 + 7 / 6 * 5 + 4 * 3 * 2 - 1 == 36
8 - 7 + 6 * 5 + 4 * 3 / 2 - 1 == 36
8 / 7 + 6 * 5 + 4 * 3 / 2 - 1 == 36
8 - 7 + 6 + 5 * 4 * 3 / 2 - 1 == 36
8 / 7 + 6 + 5 * 4 * 3 / 2 - 1 == 36
8 - 7 / 6 + 5 * 4 * 3 / 2 - 1 == 36
8 - 7 + 6 * 5 + 4 + 3 - 2 * 1 == 36
8 / 7 + 6 * 5 + 4 + 3 - 2 * 1 == 36
8 * 7 - 6 - 5 - 4 - 3 - 2 * 1 == 36
8 + 7 * 6 - 5 - 4 - 3 - 2 * 1 == 36
8 + 7 + 6 * 5 - 4 - 3 - 2 * 1 == 36
8 * 7 / 6 * 5 - 4 - 3 - 2 * 1 == 36
8 + 7 + 6 + 5 * 4 - 3 - 2 * 1 == 36
8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 * 3 - 2 * 1 == 36
8 * 7 - 6 * 5 + 4 * 3 - 2 * 1 == 36
8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 * 2 * 1 == 36
8 * 7 - 6 * 5 + 4 + 3 * 2 * 1 == 36
8 * 7 - 6 - 5 * 4 + 3 * 2 * 1 == 36
8 + 7 * 6 - 5 * 4 + 3 * 2 * 1 == 36
8 * 7 + 6 - 5 * 4 - 3 * 2 * 1 == 36
8 - 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 == 36
8 / 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 == 36
8 - 7 / 6 + 5 + 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 == 36
8 - 7 + 6 * 5 + 4 + 3 / 2 * 1 == 36
8 / 7 + 6 * 5 + 4 + 3 / 2 * 1 == 36
8 / 7 * 6 * 5 + 4 * 3 / 2 * 1 == 36
8 / 7 * 6 + 5 * 4 * 3 / 2 * 1 == 36
8 * 7 - 6 * 5 * 4 / 3 / 2 * 1 == 36
8 - 7 + 6 * 5 + 4 + 3 - 2 / 1 == 36
8 / 7 + 6 * 5 + 4 + 3 - 2 / 1 == 36
8 * 7 - 6 - 5 - 4 - 3 - 2 / 1 == 36
8 + 7 * 6 - 5 - 4 - 3 - 2 / 1 == 36
8 + 7 + 6 * 5 - 4 - 3 - 2 / 1 == 36
8 * 7 / 6 * 5 - 4 - 3 - 2 / 1 == 36
8 + 7 + 6 + 5 * 4 - 3 - 2 / 1 == 36
8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 * 3 - 2 / 1 == 36
8 * 7 - 6 * 5 + 4 * 3 - 2 / 1 == 36
8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 * 2 / 1 == 36
8 * 7 - 6 * 5 + 4 + 3 * 2 / 1 == 36
8 * 7 - 6 - 5 * 4 + 3 * 2 / 1 == 36
8 + 7 * 6 - 5 * 4 + 3 * 2 / 1 == 36
8 * 7 + 6 - 5 * 4 - 3 * 2 / 1 == 36
8 - 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 * 3 * 2 / 1 == 36
8 / 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 * 3 * 2 / 1 == 36
8 - 7 / 6 + 5 + 4 * 3 * 2 / 1 == 36
8 - 7 + 6 * 5 + 4 + 3 / 2 / 1 == 36
8 / 7 + 6 * 5 + 4 + 3 / 2 / 1 == 36
8 / 7 * 6 * 5 + 4 * 3 / 2 / 1 == 36
8 / 7 * 6 + 5 * 4 * 3 / 2 / 1 == 36
8 * 7 - 6 * 5 * 4 / 3 / 2 / 1 == 36

$
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9537036bff919760)</kbd>

In ful trust on my coding abilities, I choosed randomly one line and checked it with the Windows calculator – it was correct.

Notes:

1. To iterate through all possible combinations of operators, the operators `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` are mapped to 0 ... 3. As these four values can be stored with exactly 2 bits, the sequence of all operators is stored in one `unsigned`. This makes iteration through all possible combinations extremely easy – it's just incrementing the resp. `unsigned`.
2. To solve the equation, I remembered how ancient pocket calculators (without support of `()`) did this (with very limited resources). I didn't remember clearly (as it's decades ago somebody explained it to me) but was able to re-invent it. As there are only two possible precedences in `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, it is fully sufficient to work with two buffers – one for the accumulated intermediate product, one for the accumulated intermediate sum.
3. The computations are done in `int` arithmetic. That means these computations are mathematical correct with the constraint to Natural numbers and integer operations. (I didn't check for overflow/underflow/wrap-around but I've a "good feeling" for the sample numbers. According to how `solve()` works, division by 0 cannot be an issue as long as there is no `0` in input.)
4. What I left out: parsing the text into the data structures I used in my sample. I leave this as exercise...